# libGL error - Unabe to load drivers with OpengGL code in Ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, opengl

I just installed PyOpenGL and proceed practice with [this tutorial](https://noobtuts.com/python/opengl-introduction). It starts with this simple code that creates a window:

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

window = 0                                             # glut window number
width, height = 500, 400                               # window size

def draw():                                            # ondraw is called all the time
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT) # clear the screen
    glLoadIdentity()                                   # reset position

    # ToDo draw rectangle

    glutSwapBuffers()                                  # important for double buffering


# initialization
glutInit()                                             # initialize glut
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_ALPHA | GLUT_DEPTH)
glutInitWindowSize(width, height)                      # set window size
glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0)                           # set window position
window = glutCreateWindow("noobtuts.com")              # create window with title
glutDisplayFunc(draw)                                  # set draw function callback
glutIdleFunc(draw)                                     # draw all the time
glutMainLoop()
```

But when I try to run it I get this set of errors:

```
An error ocurred while starting the kernel
libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request: GLXBadContext
Major opcode of failed request: 155 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request: 6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
Serial number of failed request: 43
Current serial number in output stream: 42
X Error of failed request: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
Major opcode of failed request: 155 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request: 24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
Value in failed request: 0x0
Serial number of failed request: 42
Current serial number in output stream: 43
```

Can someone guide me on what they mean or how to fix them?

There are some discussions on the internet about this issue, but I haven't found one with strong solution. I'm using Ubuntu 16 by the way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have installed some proprietary drivers and after that things got broke. You should uninstall newly installed NVDIA driver and reinstall it. Then on main window go to search application and type additional drivers in that window select driver you installed.

If this doesn't help and you have not installed any additional drivers please type following command on terminal and see if you have this file

》》locate nouveau_dri.so

If it can't find install it and that should fix error.